# Record a live lecture from one room and stream it live to two other televisions

Tags: video, audio, streaming

I'm working on a church project and I'm not too familiar with video equipment all too much.

We need to stream a lecture to other sides of a building (at least two tv's). 
I was playing around with some ideas with IP cameras and connecting it via an Apple TV / Roku device but I can't find any combinations or guides on that working.

So I'm just gathering some information and advice into this

Answer (score 1):

Get a camera with HDMI output and plug it in to a Blackmagic Intensity PCIe card or USB/Thunderbolt unit. Then use Adobe Flash Media Encoder to take that input and encode it into an RTMP/RTSP stream that a computer can easily play on the other via the network, plugged in to a projector or TV.